# Unable to scrape google search result using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the flipkart link of a product from google search results. But when I try to print the link by matching it against the text "flipkart", it dosent print anything. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a part of the html structure:

```
<div class="r">
<a href="https://www.flipkart.com/redmi-note-7-pro-nebula-red-64- 
gb/p/itmferghuf9ky6ru" ping="/url?=https://www.flipkart.com/redmi- 
note-7-pro-nebula-red-64-gb/p/itmferghuf9ky6ru&amp">
```

The results of query are coming under the div class="r". From that div I'm trying to get the anchor tag link.

Here is my code

```
input='note 7 pro'
urllib.parse.quote_plus(input)

html = getHTML('https://www.google.co.in/search?q='+input)
main_div=html.findAll('div', {'class':'r'})

for div in main_div:
    link = div.find('a')[href]
    if 'flipkart' in link:
        print(link)
```

The output should be the full flipkart link of the product. But the program is not showing any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will certainly have a captcha from Google in several requests. Anyway, I tried to **scrape** a google page and the class on the `div` was `g`

But the link you are searching is in the `h3` with the `r` class.

So in my opinion you just have to change

```
main_div=html.findAll('div', {'class':'r'})
```

by

```
main_div=html.findAll('h3', {'class':'r'})
```

and it should work, for the moment

Comment: Thanks that worked! But what did you meant by captcha from Google?

Comment: I think (not sure) that google will display a captcha on the search page if you are trying a lot of scraping from the same IP. But you will see over the time.
Glad it worked! Maybe you can accept the answer then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To scrape just flipkart link you can do the following by using `select_one()` `bs4` method:

```py
soup.select_one('CSS_SELECTOR')
```

Code and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Scrape-Title-Link-Snippet-python):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {'q': 'flipkart redmi note 10'}
html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

filpkart_link = soup.select_one('.yuRUbf').a['href']
print(filpkart_link)

# output:
'''
https://www.flipkart.com/redmi-note-10-frost-white-64-gb/p/itm23973bd36fd21
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Basically, the main difference is that everything is already done for the end-user and you don't have to figure out how to make the parser work, e.g. maintaining the parser.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "flipkart redmi note 10",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
# [0] - index of the first results from Google Search Results
flipkart_link = results['organic_results'][0]['link']
print(flipkart_link)
# output:
'''
https://www.flipkart.com/redmi-note-10-frost-white-64-gb/p/itm23973bd36fd21
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.